# Cannot start Apache TomEE server - Deployment not found: openejb/Deployer

Tags: java, web, servlets, openejb, apache-tomee

I am trying to make a simple demo with java servlets. When I run a TomEE server on localhost it fails with the errors:

```
java.lang.Exception: deployment not found: openejb/Deployer
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2366)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1100)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:759)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.buildContainerSystem(Assembler.java:637)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.build(Assembler.java:494)
        at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init>(OpenEJB.java:150)
        at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:307)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatLoader.initialize(TomcatLoader.java:245)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.lifecycleEvent(ServerListener.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:584)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
15-Apr-2020 14:04:54.360 SEVERE [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication undeployException original cause
    java.lang.Exception: deployment not found: openejb/ConfigurationInfo
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2366)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1100)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:759)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.buildContainerSystem(Assembler.java:637)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.build(Assembler.java:494)
        at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init>(OpenEJB.java:150)
        at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:307)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatLoader.initialize(TomcatLoader.java:245)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.lifecycleEvent(ServerListener.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:584)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
15-Apr-2020 14:04:54.360 SEVERE [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication undeployException original cause
    java.lang.Exception: deployment not found: MEJB
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2366)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1100)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:759)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.buildContainerSystem(Assembler.java:637)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.build(Assembler.java:494)
        at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init>(OpenEJB.java:150)
        at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:307)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatLoader.initialize(TomcatLoader.java:245)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.lifecycleEvent(ServerListener.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:584)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
15-Apr-2020 14:04:54.361 SEVERE [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.buildContainerSystem Application could not be deployed:  openejb
    org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: openejb: Error building bean 'openejb/Deployer'.  Exception: class java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null: null
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1104)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:759)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.buildContainerSystem(Assembler.java:637)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.build(Assembler.java:494)
        at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init>(OpenEJB.java:150)
        at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:307)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatLoader.initialize(TomcatLoader.java:245)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.lifecycleEvent(ServerListener.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:584)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Error building bean 'openejb/Deployer'.  Exception: class java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null: null
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EjbJarBuilder.build(EjbJarBuilder.java:85)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.initEjbs(Assembler.java:1501)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:962)
        ... 18 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:415)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EnterpriseBeanBuilder.load(EnterpriseBeanBuilder.java:429)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EnterpriseBeanBuilder.loadClass(EnterpriseBeanBuilder.java:405)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EnterpriseBeanBuilder.build(EnterpriseBeanBuilder.java:82)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EjbJarBuilder.build(EjbJarBuilder.java:68)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: cannot create unique file, please set java.io.tmpdir to a writable folder or create work folder
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.<clinit>(DeployerEjb.java:112)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
        at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1024)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.<clinit>(DeployerEjb.java:96)
        ... 26 more
```

I am using **JDK 12** with **TomEE webprofile 8.0.1**. I tried to start the server from {tomee}/bin/**startup.bat** but unfortunately there was not any difference.

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>demoServlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoServlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>12</source>
                    <target>12</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**HomeServlet.java:**

```
package web;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/")
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

webapp/WEB-INF/**web.xml**:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

**Project structure:**

```
root
 │──src
      │──main
      │     └──java
      │          └──web
      │               └──HomeServlet.java
      │──webapp
          └──WEB-INF
               └──web.xml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the stacktrace error seems permission issue in tmp dir.

```
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: cannot create unique file, please set java.io.tmpdir to a writable folder or create work folder
```

Which means application don't have write access to tmp dir.

So  you can add openejb.system.apps=false in conf/system.properties or just export CATALINA_TMPDIR to a "new tmp dir value"

Comment: I changed {tomee}/temp folder properties to full control.